# C - Socket communication (TCP)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to pass a struct variable throught a TCP connection, but i am not able to understand which is the problem. I get the variables command and id, but when i do the read for the username variables (and the ones after) the printf gives no results.

```
typedef struct _msg{ // 4+4+20+20+44+200+8=300
    int command;
    int id;
    char username[20];
    char password[20];
    char subject[44];
    char text[200];
    time_t timestamp;
} msg;




msg* get_msg(int client_socket){
     char *auxString= (char*) calloc (1, sizeof(time_t));
      msg *auxMsg= (msg*) calloc(1,sizeof(msg));

     read(client_socket, auxString , sizeof(auxMsg->command));
     auxMsg->command=strtol(auxString,NULL,10);
     printf("%d\n", auxMsg->command);
     read(client_socket, auxString, sizeof(auxMsg->id));
     auxMsg->id=strtol(auxString,NULL,10);
     printf("%d\n", auxMsg->id);

     read(client_socket, auxMsg->username, sizeof(auxMsg->username));
     printf("%s\n", auxMsg->username);
     read(client_socket, auxMsg->password, sizeof(auxMsg->password));
     printf("%s\n", auxMsg->password);
     read(client_socket, auxMsg->subject, sizeof(auxMsg->subject));
     printf("%s\n", auxMsg->subject);
     read(client_socket, auxMsg->text, sizeof(auxMsg->text));
     printf("%s\n", auxMsg->text);

     read(client_socket, auxString , sizeof(auxMsg->timestamp));
     auxMsg->timestamp=strtol(auxString,NULL,10);
     printMsg(auxMsg);
     return auxMsg;
 }

 int send_msg(int client_socket, int command, int id, char* username, char* password, char*subject, char*text, time_t timestamp){
     char* auxString=(char*) calloc (1,sizeof(time_t));

     sprintf(auxString,"%d",command);
     write(client_socket,auxString,sizeof(int));
     sprintf(auxString,"%d",id);
     write(client_socket,auxString,sizeof(int));

     write(client_socket,username,sizeof(username));
     write(client_socket,password,sizeof(password));
     write(client_socket,subject,sizeof(subject));
     write(client_socket,text,sizeof(text));

     sprintf(auxString,"%d",command);
     write(client_socket, auxString, sizeof(time_t));

     return SUCCESS;
 }
```

Comment: perhaps you should show the definition of your struct?

Comment: You should **really** take care of what `read()` and `write()` return! Read the documentation on this!

Comment: TCP is a stream, it does not know anything about messages. Do not expect the number of reads necessary to receive to match the number writes issued to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `struct` appears to contain fixed-length string fields, but in your `send_msg` function you're just passing pointers.

Therefore when you use `sizeof` you'll just be passing the *size of the pointer* (typically 4 on a 32-bit system, or 8 on a 64-bit system) instead of the *length of the string*.

I would strongly recommend changing your `send_msg` function so that it also takes a `msg*` pointer instead of individual fields, and then using a separate function to build such a structure from those fields.

Having done that, your `send_msg` function would just reduce to:

```
ssize_t send_msg(int client_socket, msg *m) {
    return write(client_socket, m, sizeof(msg));
}
```

and likewise `get_msg()` would reduce to:

```
msg *get_msg(int client_socket) {
    msg *m = malloc(sizeof(msg));
    if (m) {
        char *p = (char *)m;
        ssize_t r = 0;
        size_t n = sizeof(msg);
        while ((r = read(client_socket, p, n)) > 0) {
            n -= r;
            p += r;
        }
        if (r == -1) { /* an error occurred */
            free(m);
            m = NULL;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

i.e. (at best) a single `read` or `write` per call, with the `int` fields transferred in binary form.  The `get_msg` function shows how to keep reading until you've got the whole structure - the `send_msg` function would ideally look the same too.

There's a couple of caveats here that you should be aware of, though:

Firstly, the data transferred will always be the full size of a `struct msg`, even if the strings therein don't fill their buffers.  A more optimal protocol would transmit the string lengths and then the string data.

Secondly, the format of the binary data will be architecture dependent, so the code wouldn't work if one end was little-endian and the other was big-endian.  However the latter can be trivially fixed by using `htonl()` and related functions to convert binary fields into a canonical "network order" before transmission and `ntohl()` to convert back on receipt.

Comment: I have posted the struct!

Comment: @alk I had mentioned that in the text, but I've updated the code now anyway.

Comment: But still nitpicking: `n` shall be of `size_t` and `r` shall be of `ssize_t` according to what `sizeof` and `read()` "return". And the result of `malloc()` shall not caste in C. 1+ however.

Comment: Consquently `send_msg()` shall return `ssize_t` also.

Comment: Also there is some confusion in the nameing of the pointer to read to in `get_msg()`.

Comment: @alk that's what comes from using this functions since before `size_t` existed.  Old habits die hard, and of course I didn't throw this at a compiler for warnings ;-)

Comment: @alk and of course I actually need two pointers - one to return, and another to pass to `read()`.

Comment: Hu, yesyes, I'm so sorry for not fixing it correctly! @Alnitak